# Why do some recite Tehillim 121 at Maariv?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, maariv

I thought reciting Tehillim as Tefillah at and after Maariv was not done. Why do some recite Tehillim 121 before Aleinu at Maariv?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Sefard%2C_Weekday_Maariv%2C_Amidah.105?lang=bi

It seems only be in nusach sefard. It says also before tehillim 121 before Aleinu "In Israel most who follow nusach sefard say psalms 121" I used to own a koren nusach sefard as well and i think it was in there as well before Aleinu. I've been using Tehillas HaShem for a long while now and it doesn't have 121 before Aleinu at Maariv. The way its introduced makes it sound like its recited daily at Maariv before Aleinu and not only in times of distress but as part of the actual sefard liturgy.

Comment: @Niel Also Nusah Edot Hamizrah https://www.sefaria.org.il/Siddur_Edot_HaMizrach%2C_Weekday_Arvit%2C_Amidah.67?lang=bi

Comment: @Joel K yeah it sorta made me curious since tehillim shouldn't be recited at night as a tefillah, and it seems part of the actual liturgy wether times of distress or not.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98367/14850

Comment: @Joel K Ashaynem dank for the share.

Comment: Some of the information in these comments should go in the question